# How to Submit a Form to a Sister Domain on Sitemagic CMS

Tags: html, forms, content-management-system

I have a form on SiteA.com and I have software on SiteB.com that uses this form on it's site. How do I get the form on SiteA to submitt to the program on SiteB?

The form code is:

```
<table cellspacing="10" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><tr><td>
<form action="http://rootdomain.com/SiteB(addondomain)/Program/s.php" method=GET>
<strong><font color="#660000">Your name (First, Last):</font></strong><br>
<input type="text" name="f" style="background-color : #FFFFFF" size=11 maxlength=40> 
<input type="text" name="l" style="background-color : #FFFFFF" size=11 maxlength=40>
<br><br>
<strong><font color="#000066">Email address:</font></strong><br>
<input type="text" name="e" style="background-color : #FFFFFF" size=20 maxlength=50>
<input type="image" src="http://rootdomain.com/SiteB(addondomain)/Program/images/go-button.gif" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="r" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="sub">
<input type="hidden" name="ref" value="none">
<br>
<font color="#003300">HTML: <input type="RADIO" name="h" value="1">Yes  
<input type="RADIO" name="h" value="0" checked="checked">No<br>
</font></form>
</td></tr></table>`
```

Update: I have discovered that the form works on the sister site IF I put it in a generic html page. HOWEVER, I'm using a CMS called SiteMagic which, simple as it is, seems to have restricted the forms ability to function when embedded on my SiteMagic pages. How can I stop that? For some reason when embedded in the CMS pages the form button does not redirect to a confirmation page, it does not submit the info to the data gathering program. Can you help me determine why? and how can it be fixed without abandoning my CMS?

Comment: OK, for anyone else who runs into this problem, I just got a response from the Sitemagic people: 
> "
You can't paste form code into Sitemagic CMS. The reason for this is that Sitemagic CMS is a statefull application that preserves its state using a global <form> element. A form within another form is not supported by browsers. The easiest solution is to use the "External Modules" extension which will enable you to load any external resource within Sitemagic CMS. Check out this simple tutorial: sitemagic.org/cms-guide/MoreExternalModules.html "
>

Comment: Unfortunately their method ALSO seems to require that I have the form(aka external module) displaying on some other page outside the CMS --which results in the same issues as that of the iframe method. It seems I must create a page outside of the CMS for each new form and reference that, vs. generating HTML form code via my PHP form software. Once the form is embedded on an outside page I think I can use either the iframe or ExternalModules method. I'll probably just find a new CMS. Thank you @Rebule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to achieve and there are several options for you to choose from. [Sitemagic CMS](http://sitemagic.org) is very flexible.

Personally I would create an extension that would send the data using the SMRequest class:

```
$data = new SMKeyValueCollection();
$data["Username"] = "Casper";
$data["Age"] = "29";
$data["Mail" = "dsf@sdf.com";
SMRequest::Post("http://siteB.com/create.php", $data);
```

More information here:
http://sitemagic.org/developers/api/#base/SMRequest

However, the easiest way would be to temporarily change the form target (action) using JavaScript - preferably from an extension:

```
var smForm = document.getElementById("SMForm");
var oldTarget = smForm.action;

smForm.action = "http://siteB.com/save.php";
smForm.submit();
smForm.action = oldTarget;
```

Answer (score 0):

First try, form action=http://siteb.com/program/s.php

To 
Action= /path-to-file/siteb/program/s.php

If that didnt solve the problem with Your CMS then try adding the form directly to the template or use Ajax, jquery to get the form submitted. All CMS allows jquery scripts except You chose the editor to filter scripts.

Best for You with Your CMS is to use iframe> to get form on siteA from siteB(create form on siteB with s.php on same folder).

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you @Rebule Unfortunately there were complications with those. I thought the iframe would be good but I would the have to create a page with the form on it outside of the CMS for it to link to, and do that each time I make a new form (so instead of it being one form for one page, its would be one form on two pages for one page. All those pages could get a bit cluttered. Sitemagic tells me that changing the action path wont help because it's still "a form within another form". Thank you though, those were the kind of answers I was looking for -they just didn't work this time..